# Winforms Progress Bar update

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar

I'm a new programmer to C# and I would like some help. I searched a lot but I didn't find a simple example. Please see the code below:

```
 public partial class Welcome : Form
 {
     public Welcome()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Compare comp = new Compare();
         comp.Comparator();
     }
 }
```

In the `Compare` `Class` I have a simple method that contains a simple loop:

```
 public class Compare
 {
     public void Comparator()
     {
         for (int i;i<val;i++)
         { /* ............. */ }
     }

 }
```

I want to update the `ProgressBar` in parallel with an increment of the value of `i`.

Comment: Consider `BackgroundWorker` threading:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.  It has built-in mechanisms for doing work and reporting progress back to a UI.

Comment: That question have been asked a [lot of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697168/progress-bar-c-sharp). [Seriously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068720/winforms-progress-bar-does-not-update-c). [A lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470927/c-sharp-winform-progressbar-and-backgroundworker). [Please at least do a google search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259949/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar-in-c). [Thanks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546222/adding-a-progress-bar)

Answer (score 1):

You said you searched a lot... where? These are most trivial things with very well described examples in MSDN

in BackgroundWorker_doWork method:

```
Parallel.For(0, val, i =>
{
    ...
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);
});
```

in BackgroundWorker_reportProgress method:

```
wf.progressBar.Value=wf.progressBar.Value + 1;
```

in Main form constructor

```
public Welcome()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Compare.wf=this;
}
```

in

```
public class Compare
{
    static Welcome wf;
    public void Comparator()
    {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fairly sure the progress bar is on the main form. Your solution doesn't report it back to the calling form

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing that is:

```
     public class Compare
     {
         public void Comparator()
         {
             progressBar.Value = 0;
             progressBar.Maximum = val;
             progressBar.Step = 1;
             for (int i;i<val;i++)
             { 
                 /* ............. */ 
                 progressBar.PerformStep();
             }
         }
     }
```